# Component not updating properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, reactive-programming

I have two component organisms:

- FilterComponent
- TableComponent

Both of them component will render into one page.
filter component will pass the props into table component for update data in table. This is the simple part of my code.

`FilterComponent`

```js
passUpdateToParent() {
  this.$emit("update", this.filter) // I just emit this variable
},

processResetFilter() {
  this.filter = {
    search: {},
    value: ""
  }
  this.passUpdateToParent()
},
```

`TableComponent`

```js
...

props : {
 filter: {default : () => ({}), 
 ... // another props
},
methods:{
 testGetFilter(){
   console.log(this.filter) // this props not update if I call in one time, but when I call in twice this props updated.
 }
}

<template>
 <section>
  {{ filter }} <!-- updated properly -->
 </section>
</template>
```

---

`PageComponent`

```js
components: {
 FilterComponent: () => import("@/components/FilterComponent"),
 TableComponent: () => import("@/components/TableComponent"),
},
data :() => ({
 filter :{}
}),
methods : {
 processGetFilter(value){
  this.filter = value
 },
}

<template>
 <section>
   <filter-component @update="processGetFilter" />
   <table-component :filter="filter" />
 </section>
</template>
```

I don't know why my component is not updating the props when I call the props inside of my methods, but if I am rendering or print it into vue template the component properly updates.

PS: I am using nuxt v2.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you did not bind the `filter` in `filter-component`

---

it's not a good idea to update the props directly which may cause errors.

use `computed` for your sub component instead of updating the props dircetly

**FilterComponent**

```js
// update the computed filter instead of props value
<input v-model="filter.value"/>

....
props: {
    value: {
        default: () => {}
    }
},
computed: {
    filter: {
        get() {
            return this.value;
        },
        set(newFilter) {
            this.$emit('input', newFilter)
        }
    }
}
```

in your **PageComponent**:

```html
<filter-component v-model="filter" />
```

Comment: Ah i see thank you for your time @Dengsihan, but the filter value is not only contain text field. that's why i doesn't use v-model/vue binding. but i was solve my code using this methods.

Comment: @ikbalmaulana not mutating props is important as mentioned Deng. Use ESlint and follow the guidelines if you want to have some clean code.